# No veo el resto de las aplicaciones instaladas en una lista

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estoy tratando de listar las aplicaciones instaladas en el teléfono, pero no consigo que se visualicen aplicaciones como **WhatsApp, Instagram, etc**. Lo he intentado de varias maneras pero, no consigo verlas en la lista. Esta es una de las formas en las que lo he intentado:

```
    final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    ArrayList<Paquetes> paquetesArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    @SuppressLint("QueryPermissionsNeeded") List <ApplicationInfo> installedApplications = packageManager.getInstalledApplications(0);
    for(ApplicationInfo applicationInfo : installedApplications){
        if((applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0){
            Paquetes paquetes = new Paquetes(applicationInfo.loadLabel(packageManager).toString(), applicationInfo.packageName, applicationInfo.loadIcon(packageManager));
            paquetesArrayList.add(paquetes);
            paquetesArrayList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Paquetes::getNombreApp));
        }
    }
```

Si bien, esta forma me muestra muchas apps no me muestra las que ya mencioné por ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De la siguiente forma, he acortado la cantidad de aplicaciones:

```
    final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    @SuppressLint("QueryPermissionsNeeded")
    List<PackageInfo> packageInfoList = packageManager.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
    ArrayList<Paquetes> paquetesArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(PackageInfo packageInfo : packageInfoList){
        if(!aplicaciónDelSistema(packageInfo)){
            Paquetes paquetes = new Paquetes(packageInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(packageManager).toString(), packageInfo.applicationInfo.packageName, packageInfo.applicationInfo.loadIcon(packageManager));
            paquetesArrayList.add(paquetes);
        }
    }

boolean aplicaciónDelSistema(PackageInfo pkgInfo){
    if((pkgInfo.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_UPDATED_SYSTEM_APP) != 0)
        return false;
    else if((pkgInfo.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0)
        return true;
    else if((pkgInfo.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_INSTALLED) != 0)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

Pero tampoco muestra las aplicaciones que ya mencioné:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que figuren en la lista?

Comment: Pero en installedApplications  si vienen todas las aplicaciones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu aplicación seguramente esta orientada para Android 11 y de ahora en adelante debes tomar en cuenta lo que indica la documentación:

> Llame a `getInstalledApplications()` o `getInstalledPackages()`. **Ambos
> métodos deberían devolver una lista filtrada.**

Esto indica que si haces uso de `getInstalledPackages()` ya no obtendrás todos los paquetes de las aplicaciones

```
 List<PackageInfo> packageInfoList = packageManager.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
```

Lo que debes de realizar ahora es que tendras que agregarlos dentro de tu `AndroidManifest.xml` en tu etiqueta `<queries>`:

```
<queries>
    <package android:name="com.whatsapp" />
    <package android:name="com.android.chrome" />
</queries>
...
...
...
```

o definir el permiso `QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES` dentro de tu `AndroidManifest.xml` :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES"/>
```

Revisa este artículo en donde se comenta acerca de la "Visibilidad de paquetes":

[Cómo verificar si una app Android está instalada en tu dispositivo](https://medium.com/@GoogleDroids/c%C3%B3mo-verificar-si-una-app-android-est%C3%A1-instalada-en-tu-dispositivo-336a303fc84a)

Comment: La verdad es que estoy trabajando con android 7 a posteriores, pero no me percate que el teléfono en el que estoy ejecutando la aplicación tiene Android 11. Gracias por hacérmelo notar

Comment: De hecho no tiene que ver mucho el sistema operativo propiamente si no la versión con la que compilamos la apllicación en este caso 11 o posterior. Pero siempre Google nos indica actualizar la orientación del sistema operativo para poder subir la aplicación a Google Play por lo tanto siempre debemos revisar este tipo de cambios.